# GitHub repo failing Travis CI build because of "console-browserify"

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

I have an NPM project that uses Jasmine-Node for running unit tests.

My test suite (npm test) runs fine locally, but when I push my commits to GitHub my Travis CI build fails.

https://travis-ci.org/arthurakay/LintRoller/jobs/7002012

Does anyone know what is happening here? I don't think I need "console-browserify" but for some reason the build believes it's necessary.

For reference, see my ./hooks/pre-commit bash script to see where I call the unit test suite.

Comment: I am wondering if JSHint could be to blame here - https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1055

I may need to specify specific versions of my dependent packages, not just >=x.x.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with JSHint, which was corrected in their own repo shortly after I asked this question.

https://github.com/jshint/jshint/commit/28cfa2e369b31afb6ccfb44ee1f0d7df71170133

In short, JSHint now requires console-browserify but at the moment I ran my build their repo was broken (or in some state that broke my build). Having said that, I probably *do* need to test against a specific version of each of my dependencies.

Comment: Glad you got this fixed again. Any chance you could accept this answer to mark it as the right one for others who get this same issue? It also marks this question as answered :)

Answer (score -1):

you could always install console-browserify to check if that solves the error.

```
npm install -S console-browserify
```

Perhaps you have `console-browserify` installed globally on your local machine

Comment: I *could* do that, but I don't want unnecessary dependencies. Also, I don't have console-browserify installed locally, either globally or within this package.